# Using gpu_from_host in scan()

Tags: python, gpu, theano

I want to use `scan()` in order to create loops which are executed on the GPU. However, if I run a function the result is from type `numpy.ndarray` which indicates, that the result is transferred to the host.

How can I make sure that the data is not getting transferred to the host machine? I cannot find an example where `gpu_from_host` is being used for that purpose.

Is it possible to do that?